# Axis Connection Timeout

Tags: web-services, wsdl, timeout, connection, axis

My Axis based client program tries to connect to a webservice, when the server is down I don't want to wait too much time . I want to wait max 3 seconds, So I need to set a timeout.

There is attribute CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY on the Call class -Axis' JAXRPC Dynamic Invocation . I don't know how to use it. serached alot the web and didn't find out how to do it.I cannot get connection timeouts to work.

Answer (score 1):

I use such definition in client proxy for Axis 1.3:

```
<bean id="serviceTarget" class="com.nxsec.log4ensics.dbmanager.ws.DMJaxRpcPortProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="customPropertyMap"><map>
    <entry key="axis.connection.timeout">
      <value type="java.lang.Integer">3000</value>
    </entry>
  </map></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Used this solution to configure a Spring JaxRpcPortClientInterceptor (and its subclass JaxRpcPortProxyFactoryBean) and it worked perfeclty. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I found here the way to set timeout by stub, it might help you.

There is a setTimeout method on the org.apache.axis.client.Stub class, which is the class all emitted stubs extend.

Here is how to set the timeout given a service named Foo:

```
FooServiceLocator loc = new FooServiceLocator();
FooService binding = loc.getFooService();
org.apache.axis.client.Stub s = (Stub) binding;
s.setTimeout(1000);  // 1 second, in miliseconds
```

See: http://ws.apache.org/axis/faq.html#faq17

Comment: For whoever reads this...apparently that's a socket timeout, not a connection timeout. It will come into play if the time between package and package exceeds the value having been set, but not if the server is down.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work well:

```
long soTimeout = 2 * 60 * 1000; // Two minutes
Stub stub = new TestStub();
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(soTimeout);
 
//or
 
int timeOutInMilliSeconds = 2 * 60 * 1000; // Two minutes
Stub stub = new TestStub();
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(
                 HTTPConstants.SO_TIMEOUT, timeOutInMilliSeconds);
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(
                 HTTPConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, new Integer(timeOutInMilliSeconds));
```

Found here: https://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/how-to-configure-timeout-duration-at-client-side-for-axis2-web-services/